# How to make \bibname to \LARGE?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex

I wanna make \bibname to \LARGE References. But when I use

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{\LARGE References}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

then bibliography changes successfully. 
[image]
However, bibliography in contents changes \LARGE size too.
[image]
How can I fix it to normal size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The `\bibname` macro is just that: the name of the reference list. It should not have any formatting inside it (as you have discovered.)  What documentclass are you using? And what package are you using to produce the bibliography?

Comment: I'm using memoir class

Comment: Please look at the new answer added by esdd and consider changing your your accept vote. That answer shows the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a fontsize command in the redefinition of `\bibname`. Maybe its used at another place in the document.

With `memoir` class you can redefine `\bibsection` to get the desired reference header:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Reference}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
  \let\origchaptitlefont\chaptitlefont
  \renewcommand*\chaptitlefont{\origchaptitlefont\LARGE}%
  \chapter*{\bibname}
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
  \fi
  \prebibhook
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (more if I could) :).  This should be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below codes helps you to meet your requirement:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{memoir}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\LARGE References}
\nobibintoc% this trick helps not to include reference head in TOC by auto
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}%%added the reference head in TOC
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Comment: The page number of the bibliography  in TOC is wrong.